# how to run Emacs when SSH-ing from Linux to Mac OS X (with XForwarding)?

Tags: linux, macos, emacs, ssh

At work I get a choice of two laptops to use, Windows or Mac. Being a linux guy, I thought the MacBook Pro will be a good fit.

So I bring the MacBook Pro laptop home, and realize it doesn't have a right-ctrl key. And the bottom panel is annoying as hell. So I say, no problem, I'll sort all that out later, for now I'll use it as a server and remotely ssh into it from my crispy Xfce workstation environment. Well...

I've spent about a day trying to figure out:

**How to ssh into the mac from my Fedora workstation, run emacs and have it show up (XForwarded) on my linux workstation ?** You know like this:

[image]

I've installed [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/) and changed `/etc/sshd_config` and `/private/etc/sshd_config` with:

```
X11Forwarding yes
XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

Mind you, `xeyes` works, and so does `xclock`, yay !!!

[image][image]

Apparently X forwarding is working okay, since other gui apps are showing up remotely. But as for Emacs, foggetaboutit.

The default Emacs from `/usr/bin/emacs` just runs it in `-nw` mode. Then I've installed [the latest Emacs 24.3](http://emacsformacosx.com/) (into `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs`). This time, if I'm physically logged into the laptop (i.e. from the laptop keyboard) running Emacs from ssh shows up on the laptop's screen !!! WTF? If I logout of the laptop, then I get:

```
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
```

I'm at my wits ends. Any ideas why other X apps work? Anything special about Emacs?

Comment: the question title says "Linux to Mac OS X". but in the detailed question, you are running emacs on the mac and displaying it on linux. i would suggest changing the question title to "Mac OS X to Linux". in any case, i had the same question and tried many other things for hours, before seeing the "sudo port install emacs +x11" answer below that saved the day.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @giardia. I see what you're saying. I reworded the title from ``how to run Emacs in "ssh -X" from Linux to Mac..`` to ``how to run Emacs when SSH-ing from Linux to Mac...``. I believe this makes it even clearer. By using "SSH" as a verb, and inflecting it, we produce an actually correct english sentence form. I think this is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Emacs.app` binary is built to use Mac OS X's window system (we call it "ns" around here), which has nothing to do with X11, so you can't forward it over the network to another host.  Instead, you want to install another Emacs on your Mac, which is built to use the X11 window system (so you can use it locally via Xquartz (which lets X11 clients use the native Mac OS X display), or you can use it remotely like any other X11 client).

The easiest way is probably to built it yourself: get the `emacs-24.3.tar.gz` source code and compile it with `./configure --with-x; make`.

Comment: ps: @VelimirMlaker - you can also run emacs on any machine and connect to a remote filesystem via SSH. the connection path looks like: `/ssh:user@host#sshport:/remote/path/to/open`

Comment: this doesn't appear to work. I've run a clean build using `--with-x` but even so the resulting emacs binary insists on running the local GUI. Has something changed in the meantime?

Comment: See this https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28840/os-x-emacs-difference-between-x11-vs-ns-vs-cocoa - it's necessary to specify `--with-ns=no`

Comment: @robert: Hmm.. I'd have expected that `--with-x` is sufficient, so I think it's likely a bug which would deserve to be reported.

Comment: i spent quite a while trying various combinations of "--without-dbus", "--with-x", "--with-x-toolkit=motif", "--with-ns=no". these combos gave a successful, working x11 emacs on the local screen, but did not create a new x11 window when connecting remotely with port forwarding.

Answer (score 2):

With Mac Ports x11 or gtk variant has to be selected, like this:

```
sudo port install emacs +x11
```

or that:

```
sudo port install emacs +gtk
```

Comment: I tried the "brew" version, and even it didn't work!

Comment: i tried "sudo port install emacs +x11" and it worked with no fuss. this was after several hours of trying other things like homebrew, fink, compiling source, etc. thank you 1000x for this answer, @mariusm !!

Comment: "sudo port install emacs +x11" still works today, installed on Mac OS 13 Ventura, M2 processor, with MacPorts 2.8.1, Xquartz 2.8.5, emacs 28.2.